# HTML object tag to embed a web page

Tags: html, embed

We have a feature in our application which allows users to select a set of assets (images, videos etc.) and generate an embed code for those, which can be embedded in another web page. As of now we use iframes to implement in the embed code where page pointed by src attribute of iframe spits out HTML to embed.

For some security reasons we want to get rid of iframes and replace that with something else like an object tag, script tag etc.

My question is about object tag. Primary use of object tag seems to be to embed a video, a pdf etc. I know it can be used to embed an entire webpage just like what we want. But my question is - is that recommended? The webpage we want to embed will have a set of assets with options to sort, download, share, preview those assets.

So will it be a good practice to use object tag for embedding such a complex web page? Or is it meant for minimal usage like embedding a video clip, a slideshow etc.?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html

Comment: What security concerns do you have with iframes? What makes you think that object won't have the same issues?

Comment: @AllisonC - That page pretty much answers my question.

Comment: @Quentin - The security concerns I mentioned are similar to what is mentioned on this page - http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2007/10/24/iframes-security-summary/ - Do you think objects would have the same kind of issues? Also it seems iframes are not displayed correctly on mobile browsers.

Comment: @Mandar — Every single one of those describes attacks that can be made if the attacker gets the victim to visit a page they created that uses iframes. None of them are problems related to using an iframe in your own page. Most of them also depend on (now fixed) security holes in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of technology you are using, you can do something similar.

With your request you are getting into the portlet/web part discussion, where you want to embed portlets (mini apps). There is no object tag you can use (to my knowledge its only image, applet and iframe I think) from the client side, but you might be able to pre-load the parts before you send the user the final page (say, like wordpress widgets in php).

Otherwise you need to go the Javascript route, and do some kind of lazy loading of your 'widget/applications' as needed.